Wrong behaviour of GDI+ DrawLines with PointF
The following code:
            Graphics g(hdc);

            Pen pen(Color(0, 0, 0), 10.0f);

            std::vector<Point> line1;
            line1.push_back({ 100, 100 });
            line1.push_back({ 100, 70 });
            line1.push_back({ 100, 100 });

            g.DrawLines(&pen, line1.data(), line1.size());


            std::vector<PointF> line2;
            line2.push_back({ 200.0f, 100.0f });
            line2.push_back({ 200.0f, 70.0f });
            line2.push_back({ 200.1f, 100.0f });

            g.DrawLines(&pen, line2.data(), line2.size());

Provides the following weird results:

Image (1) provided as an exemplar and ruler to show where Y value 70 is, and image (2) shows the defect where the line strikes far behind the expected value.
Is it a bug or I misinterpret somehow the expected behavior of the GDI+ DrawLines?
(OS: Windows Version 10.0.19044.1889; SDK Version 10.0.26100.0)

can you post a full example? I'd like to see where you're getting hdc from. Also, what is the DPI-awareness of your program?

@Dai, I posted the code here, although I understand that github would be better, will do later. Just create Windows project in VS2022, copy/paste this source and here you go.

@Dai, it seems that the problem is caused by using Pen with size more than 1 with DrawLines. I created more focused question GDI+ DrawLines bug when used with Pen size more than 1. Could you please, took a look?
